How to remove the default date in flatpickr
The issue i am facing is the i don't seem to find any information about deselect the default date(current day).

flatpickr("#datepicker", {
    defaultDate: '',
    dateFormat: "d-m-Y H:i",
    enableTime: true,
    open: true,
    inline: true,
    minDate: "today",
});

I try to use the "defaultDate" as many examples in the web but nothing seems to work. I have not find any information in the documentation except "defaultDate".
I try as well to use onChange , onReady and onOpen nothing seems to work.
 onChange: function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
                    instance.clear(); 


Lookin the source code and/or using the DevTools inspector, you can tell that the culprit is the class .today. So let's remove it on the event of open.


flatpickr("#date", {

  onOpen: [
    function(selectedDates, dateStr, instance) {
      instance.calendarContainer.querySelectorAll(".flatpickr-day").forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove("today"))
    },
  ],

});
.flatpickr-day.today {
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr/dist/flatpickr.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/flatpickr"></script>

<input id="date">




Thank you so much, but this doesn't work when the flatpickr is open by default witch i need. Still you answer provide a solution to my question so many thanks !

What i figure out is that with the solution of @IT goldman
and windows.onload it works like a charm! Much thanks again!
window.onload = (event) => {
document.querySelectorAll(".flatpickr-day").forEach(elem => elem.classList.remove("today"))};

